# Calculating an expanding rank on pandas timedeltas

Tags: python, pandas, rolling-computation

I've got a dataframe with a column of a time trial race split times defined as timedeltas. The rows are ordered by the original start time of each competitor from first starter onwards. I want to calculate the rank of each competitor at the split at the point at which that competitor crossed the split line. I'd like the output to look like the `expanding_rank` column in this little toy example. While Rider2 was eventually 4th, at the moment the passed the split point they were ranked second and Rider1 was initially ranked 1st because they were the first rider through the split point but eventually ranked 3rd.

```
name    split_time          expanding_rank
Rider1  00:00:48.857987136  1
Rider2  00:00:49.297997592  2
Rider3  00:00:47.381634176  1
Rider4  00:00:49.409940252  4
Rider5  00:00:47.678197043  2
```

To do this I think I want an expanding window calculation that ranks all of the split times up to and including the current row. I figured I could do this with a `df['split_time'].expanding(1).rank()` but it appears that the `expanding` function doesn't have a `rank` option. I'm a bit stuck as to how I should go about it.

I tried adapting [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14440187/rank-data-over-a-rolling-window-in-pandas-dataframe) with the `df.column_name.expanding.apply()` syntax but got this error: `ops for Expanding for this dtype timedelta64[ns] are not implemented`

Anyone got any ideas?!

Comment: Please provide the entire error output, as well as a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried resetting the index to split_time?
`df.set_index('split_time')`
I got this idea after looking up your error message from here
[Pandas Rolling Window - datetime64[ns] are not implemented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38415314/pandas-rolling-window-datetime64ns-are-not-implemented)

Comment: I'm not sure that works for me. If I understood that comment correctly that was simply removing the datetime column from the calculation as the OP didn't mind if there wasn't a rolling calc on that column. I specifically want to perform a rolling (or in this case expanding) calculation on a time based column.

Comment: Maybe someone else can help with your problem (-: